# i have the sql table name station i which i have column name id,city

Tags: mysql, sql

Find the difference between the total number of CITY entries in the table and the number of distinct CITY entries in the table.

I have tried the following:

```
select  from STATION where (count(CITY) from STATION) - (count(distinct CITY) from STATION)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query can solve your requirement:

```
SELECT COUNT(city) - COUNT(DISTINCT city) FROM Station;
```

You can also check my answer in [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3eeWFepxQFQ7SPzs2chGjs/0) with data

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(city) - COUNT(DISTINCT city) FROM station;
```

Explanation:
The COUNT(city) counts all the rows with non-NULL values in the city column.
The COUNT(DISTINCT city) counts all the distinct values in the city column.
The difference between the two is the number of duplicate rows.

Comment: select  from STATION where (count(CITY) from STATION) - (count(distinct CITY) from STATION)   i do this but it shows error